# Test failed when I mock throwError()

Tags: angular, jestjs

I tried to test the 'error case' of a method, but I think that if I mock a method, this mock is impacting all of my others tests.

So I try to separate the success case and the error case of my method into 2 describe.

When I launch the tests coverage, the error case is covered but the test in the console is failing...

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/21/5/1558683399-test1.png

Console msg :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/21/5/1558683502-test2.png

This is the method:

```
getAgreementSelector() {
this.isLoading = true;

this.frameworkAgreements$ = this.entityManager.getEntity(AgreementSelectorEntity, {})
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    map((dataEntity: any) => dataEntity.value),
    filter((data: Array<IFrameworkAgreement>) => !!data && data.length > 0));

this.frameworkAgreements$.subscribe((data: Array<IFrameworkAgreement>) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.agreementValue = data;
  this.error = false;
  const sessionStorageFAId = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedAgreementId');
  if (sessionStorageFAId) {
    this.onCustomerSelected(sessionStorageFAId);
  } else {
    this.onCustomerSelected(this.agreementValue[0].id.toString());
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < this.agreementValue.length; j++) {
    if (this.agreementValue[j].id.toString() === sessionStorageFAId) {
      this.selectedFrameworkAgreement = this.agreementValue[j].id.toString();
    }
  }
}, (error: any) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  if (error.status === 404 || error.status === 500 || error.status === 403) {
    this.hideErrorFlag = true;
    this.error = true;
  }
});
```

}

And the test :

```
it('should set error variables if there is an error (status 404)', () => {

    // arrange
    UtilsTest.mockReturnValue(component['entityManager'], 'getEntity', throwError({ status: 404 }));

    // act
    component.getAgreements();

    component.agreements$.subscribe(() => {
      // assert
      expect(component.isLoadingDetails).toBeFalsy();
      expect(component.hideErrorFlag).toBeTruthy();
      expect(component.errorDetails).toBeTruthy();
    });

  }
);
```

Thank you !

Comment: not sure if this is your problem, but you should use `fakeAsync` in the test

Comment: I tried with async method with try/catch, the solution below from Antonis work as expected ! :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try like that:

```
it('should set error variables if there is an error (status 404)', async(() => {
  spyOn(component['entityManager'], 'getEntity').and.throwError({ status: 404 });

  try {
    await component.getAgreements();
  } catch (e) {
    expect(component.isLoadingDetails).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.hideErrorFlag).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.errorDetails).toBeTruthy();
  }
}));
```

Comment: You're welcome! I remembered I had a similar case. Most probably you need to run that in `async` mode. I will update the answer